How to Implement an Automatic Points Discount System in WooCommerce Including Tax and Additional Fees?
I’m developing an automatic points discount system in WooCommerce, where users can apply their earned points as a discount on their next purchase. However, I’m having issues with getting the discount to account for taxes and additional fees like shipping or service charges.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
Desired Functionality
Full Discount Including Tax:

Suppose a user has earned $200 in points, and on their next purchase, they have a subtotal of $180 + $20 (tax). The total amount they should pay after the points discount should be $0.

If the subtotal is $190 + $20 (tax), they should only pay the remaining $10 after the $200 discount.


Including Additional Fees (Shipping, Service Fees, etc.):

If there are any additional fees, the discount should cover these as well. For example, if the user has $200 in points, and their cart contains $130 + $20 (tax) in products plus a $30 shipping fee, the discount should be applied to everything, resulting in a final total of $0.

What I’ve Tried So Far:
I’ve attempted to implement this using add_fee, but the problem is that add_fee only applies discounts to the pre-tax subtotal, and it doesn’t consider additional fees. Here’s a simplified version of what I have so far:
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_points_discount');

function apply_points_discount($cart) {
    // Assume the user has $200 in points
    $points_balance = 200;

    // Calculate the subtotal (pre-tax) and add the discount
    $cart_total = $cart->get_subtotal();
    $discount = min($points_balance, $cart_total);

    // Apply the discount as a negative fee
    $cart->add_fee(__('Points Discount', 'woocommerce'), -$discount);
}

The code above works for basic discounts but has the following issues:

It only applies the discount to the subtotal, ignoring tax. For example, if the cart subtotal is $180 with $20 tax, it applies a $180 discount, not the full $200 needed to bring the total to zero.
It doesn’t account for additional fees like shipping. If there’s a $30 shipping fee, it doesn’t apply the discount to cover this fee, which means the user still has to pay for it even if they have enough points.

Requirements Recap

The points discount should apply to the total amount, covering the subtotal, taxes, and any additional fees.
If the points cover the full amount, the final amount at checkout should be zero.

What I Need Help With
How can I implement this functionality in WooCommerce so that the discount correctly considers the entire cart total (including tax and fees) and brings the total to zero if the points cover everything?
Any advice on the best approach or insights into the WooCommerce API that could help achieve this would be appreciated!

Example for clarification:
Suppose I have the following:

Points balance: $200
Cart subtotal: $130
Tax: $20
Shipping fee: $30

Expected Result:

The points discount should cover all items, taxes, and fees, bringing the final total to $0.


The main problem here is that all prices and amounts use taxes, but your points don't, meaning that you should convert them to an amount excluding taxes to use them in your negative fee, because negative fees always apply taxes. So you need a conversion function for your points. When you will solve this, ask a new question related to get the shipping cost inside woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees hook.

@LoicTheAztec I don't think this is correct. Even if the user has 500 points, with a $200 product in the cart, it only applies a $180 discount. WooCommerce only applies the negative fee up to the pre-tax product price.
